# How to programmatically Register a Company and Are There APIs Available for Fast Registration?

Tags: limited-liability-company

I am currently exploring the process of registering a company in various countries, and I'm interested in understanding how to do this programmatically or through APIs to streamline the registration process. My goal is to find a jurisdiction where company registration can be completed quickly, ideally in a matter of minutes.

Specifically, I have the following questions:

1. Fast Registration: Are there any countries where it's possible to register a company in just a few minutes or with minimal delay, provided that all necessary information is readily available? If so, which countries offer such rapid registration?
2. APIs for Company Registration: In jurisdictions where fast registration is possible, do they provide APIs or online platforms that allow for programmatically submitting registration information? If yes, which countries offer such APIs, and how can they be accessed?
3. Requirements: What are the typical requirements for company registration in these fast-registration jurisdictions? Are there any specific conditions or criteria that need to be met to take advantage of expedited registration?
   I would greatly appreciate any insights or resources you can provide on this topic. My aim is to identify the most efficient and user-friendly jurisdictions for registering a company, particularly those that offer fast, digital registration processes.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Registering a company has some very serious legal implications. If anyone cannot go online and do what’s needed for a company registration they should think very, very  hard whether starting a company is what they should do.

Comment: In many (most?) countries, you can't just "register a company online" either, you need to **sign legal documents** and all and give them to one or even multiple state organisations. Welcome to Bureaucracy.

Comment: Do you have an explanation for why you need to register this many companies, and is it one you wouldn't mind repeating to your local tax office?

Comment: @Trish, in the UK you _can_ register a company online. If all you want is to have a company that doesn't trade, that will cost you I either 14 or 40 pound (can\t remember) and once a year you have to send in a form - online - that you haven't been trading, plus your card number for payment.

Comment: @gnasher729 in Germany you need to file papers with the tax office for *each company* and they have to be signed and stamped and all to gain their tax number.

Comment: @Cadence Our platform allows users to easily create companies with unique email addresses. Users primarily buy and sell these companies within the platform. This straightforward process aligns with our platform's specific focus on company ownership and trading, avoiding the need for complex agreements.

Comment: @Janos So you try acting as a middleman for some completely unnecessary service. In the UK, setting up a company is absolutely trivial, there is no need to pay anyone money for it. There are lots of things that I can do either for free, or pay someone good money with a chance that they mess it up.

Comment: @gnasher729 why mustn’t such a company trade?

Comment: If your company doesn't trade, then the effort to keep it legally running (in the UK) is minimal. Once a year you fill in one form saying that it doesn't trade, so there are no taxes, and that nothing has changed about the ownership, directors etc. Once you actually trade, then you have to do taxes, possibly VAT and so on and so on, so it is real work. I needed a company at some point in 2015, so for six years it didn't actually trade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

Forming a company is very easy in most U.S. states. You can form a company online in Colorado, for example, in five or ten minutes with very little information. A federal taxpayer ID for the company takes a little more information but can be done online on a limited basis (not as easily *en masse*) in fifteen minutes or so.

Many jurisdictions also recognize the concept of a [series LLC](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/what-is-series-llc.html):

> A series LLC is a unique form of limited liability company ("LLC") in
> which the articles of formation specifically allow for unlimited
> segregation of membership interests, assets, and operations into
> independent series. Each series operates like a separate entity with a
> unique name, bank account, and separate books and records. A series
> LLC may have different members and managers in each series. The rights
> and obligations of these members and managers differ from series to
> series. Each series may enter into contracts, sue or be sued, and hold
> title to real and personal property.
>
> The most important characteristic of a series LLC is the liability
> protection that is available to each series. Assets owned by one
> series are shielded from the risk of liability of other series within
> the same series LLC. A series LLC is similar in concept to a
> corporation with several subsidiaries. However, the series LLC concept
> is designed to segregate risk within separate entities without the
> cost of setting up new entities.
>
> The series LLC is a creation of the state. Only in certain states are
> series LLCs allowed to be formed. Delaware was the first state to
> enact legislation authorizing the creation of series LLCs. Several
> states have followed suit including Illinois, Iowa, Nevada, Oklahoma,
> Tennessee, Texas, Utah and Puerto Rico. Some states, like California,
> do not allow for series LLCs to be formed under state law but series
> LLCs formed in other states can register with the state and do
> business in the state.

More details follow at the link.

Starting in 2024, many closely held companies in the U.S. will also have to make a filing with federal anti-money laundering officials with somewhat more information.

Most online company registrations and taxpayer ID number registrations require the user to identify themselves and to make statements under penalty of perjury, so it isn't clear that an app would be an acceptable alternative.

It also isn't clear why the ability to make filings at app speed would have a legitimate purpose. As a general rule, it is not necessary for a company to be registered in every state or country that customers can access it via the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

You can do it [here](https://register.business.gov.au/registration/type?type=Company). It’s online but not an API.

There are a few preliminary [steps](https://asic.gov.au/for-business/registering-a-company/steps-to-register-a-company/) including obtaining consent from the office holders; note that office holders must have (or obtain) a [Director Identification Number](https://asic.gov.au/for-business/running-a-company/company-officeholder-duties/director-identification-number/) (DIN). There are a few additional steps (using the same form) if you want to register a business for the company to run and/or to register for applicable taxes.